# SVG in SVG image looks different on Firefox and Chrome

Tags: svg

Below is a minimal working example of my problem.  The problem arises in the context of a larger JavaScript program which places images into an SVG area.  The images usually are PNGs or JPGs, but I want to support SVG as well.  The result needs to be the same on all browsers.  However, this doesn't work in the "SVG in SVG" case.  On my Win10 machine, this looks as expected on Firefox (88.0.1), but it looks slightly askew on Chrome 90.0.4430.212.  On Chrome, the black and blue lines don't intersect in one point, the blue lines extend beyond the gray area, and the whole thing simply doesn't look symmetric.  Is this is a bug in one of the browsers?  What can I do to make this look the same in both browsers?

Here's the HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <svg style="border:1px solid black" viewBox="0 0 16 9" height="450" width="800">
      <rect x="0.1" y="0.1" width="15.8" height="8.8" fill="lightgray"></rect>
      <line x1="8" y1="0" x2="8" y2="9" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.03"></line>
      <image x="0.1" y="0.1" width="15.8" height="8.8" href="foo.svg"></image>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here's `foo.svg`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="500" height="300" viewBox="0 0 500 300">
  <path stroke-width="1" stroke="blue" fill="none" d="M 0,0 L 0,300 L 500,0 L 500,300 Z" />
</svg>
```

And, yes, I know that 500/300 is not the same as 15.8/8.8.  This is on purpose.

```html
<svg style="border:1px solid black" id="svg" viewBox="0 0 16 9" height="450" width="800">
  <rect x="0.1" y="0.1" width="15.8" height="8.8" fill="lightgray"></rect>
  <line x1="8" y1="0" x2="8" y2="9" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.03"></line>
  <image x="0.1" y="0.1" width="15.8" height="8.8" href="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' width='500' height='300' viewBox='0 0 500 300'%3E%3Cpath stroke-width='1' stroke='blue' fill='none' d='M 0,0 L 0,300 L 500,0 L 500,300 Z' /%3E%3C/svg%3E"></image>
</svg>
```

Comment: This does seem like a bug in Chrome.  I recommend that you report it.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Done

Comment: Thanks. Can you post the link to the bug here please, for future reference?

Comment: I used Chrome's "Report an issue" facility.  Is there somewhere else where I can report this?  Would the Chromium project be the right place?

Comment: Ah I see. That should work.  The more direct place is at crbug.com.  I don't see your issue there yet, so I guess the ones done through the menu must get triaged before being added.  You may get a bug number in a day or two.

Comment: I haven't seen the bug so far, so I submitted it directly: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1212634